# HostBinding a FormControl to a input within a Directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular2-hostbinding

I am having trouble adding a formControl to a input via a HostBinding inside a directive attached to the Input.
Please let me know if this is a possible approach and if so how to do it.

Input

```
<input matInput searchInput>
```

The Directive (searchInput)

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[searchInput]',
})
export class SearchableSelectDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    @HostBinding('attr.[formControl]') control: FormControl = new FormControl('');

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.sub = this.control.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
            console.log(value);
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the FormControl reference you need to use `NgControl`

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[searchInput]',
})
export class SearchableSelectDirective implements AfterViewInit {
    sub: any;
    constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.sub = this.ngControl.valueChanges.subscribe((value: string) => {
            console.log(value);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to create and attach the FormControl from the directive itself

Comment: yes you need to add the `formControl` or `formControlName` in the input element

Comment: what i need to do is attach the formcontrol through directive not the html